# Show Datetime picker on click on image

Tags: javascript

Here is my code for click on image datetimepicker will open..whenever am click on c.png (calender image ) my datepicker is not open

```
         <p>
<span style="font-weight:600; font-size:16px; margin-left:6px;">Please Select Date </span>
<img src="/callme/admin/c.png"/></a>
<a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','DDMMYYYY',true,24)">
<input type="Text" id="demo1" name="demo1" maxlength="35" size="39";>

    </p>
```

this is my script code.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var pickerOpts = {
            showOn: "button"
        }; 
        $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It should be done this way

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "/callme/admin/c.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true
    });
  });
```

Refer to Jquery [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) docs.